# How do I tell the query to only use distinct on only one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to pull a report from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Miscellaneous].[BackupStatus](
    [BackupStatusId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ComputerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeOfBackup] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsSuccess] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ProgramDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BackupStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BackupStatusId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Miscellaneous].[BackupStatus] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_BackupStatus_IsSuccess]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsSuccess]
GO
```

I need to get a list of most recent backup by CompanyCode. I only want the most recent record for each company (ie CompanyCode). I believe that I need to sort the table decending and distinct but I cannot figure it out.

```
SELECT Distinct CompanyCode, ComputerName, DateTimeOfBackup, 
                [Description], IsSuccess, [Message], 
                [Exception], ProgramDate, BackupStatusId
FROM Miscellaneous.BackupStatus
ORDER BY DateTimeOfBackup DESC
```

I'm getting back all records still. How do I tell the query to use distinct on only one field?

**UPDATE**

I hope to add some clarity to what I need.

[image]

In this case, it should only return records 4262 and 4266, since they are the most recent unique for that CompanyCode.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results. It seems likely you want to use `row_number()` and filter only row number 1.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @dalek I really feel like you are attacking me. I would appreciate you didn't help me further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT won't help here. You can use a windowed ROW_NUMBER() function to assign ordinals and then filter by ordinal = 1.

Something like:

```
SELECT CompanyCode, ComputerName, DateTimeOfBackup, 
       [Description], IsSuccess, [Message], 
       [Exception], ProgramDate, BackupStatusId
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyCode ORDER BY DateTimeOfBackup DESC)
    FROM Miscellaneous.BackupStatus
) A
WHERE A.Ordinal = 1 -- Just the latest
ORDER BY CompanyCode
```

This can also be coded using a CTE (common table expression):

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyCode ORDER BY DateTimeOfBackup DESC)
    FROM Miscellaneous.BackupStatus
)
SELECT CompanyCode, ComputerName, DateTimeOfBackup, 
       [Description], IsSuccess, [Message], 
       [Exception], ProgramDate, BackupStatusId
FROM A
WHERE A.Ordinal = 1 -- Just the latest
ORDER BY CompanyCode
```

Comment: This is known duplicate (as I have linked to), you should always flag a duplicate rather than answering it.

Comment: @DaleK - Is there a topic-specific FAQ list that points to community recommended standard answers, how-to articles, or similar? I could start building my own favorite references, but don't want to duplicate effort. Sometimes searches return a mix of good and bad matches or good answers buried in more complexity than needed for a simple question.

Comment: No, you have to maintain your own, but you've been active here a while now so I'm sure you're started to see common patterns with the questions. So keep a list as you find them and then flag them as duplicates.

Comment: Nonetheless @TN thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed. I understand now how to do it thanks to your help.